# Relink Issue sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, dependencies

When importing sklearn I have following error:

```
python3: Relink `/home/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.libs/libgomp-3300acd3.so.1.0.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_getres'
python3: Relink `/home/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.libs/libgomp-3300acd3.so.1.0.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault
```

I have tried to install sklearn with `apt install` but that did not work. 
I am aware that this is a dependency issue but I tried a lot to make it work again and maybe there is someone out here facing the same issue. 
The sklearn version is `0.22.2`.

Answer (score 1):

So I did not find a clean solution on relinking the libraries but I could solve the issue with the usage of a docker container instead of a virtual environment. I created **a docker image** with `python3.8`.

This way I overcame the broken installations of my `python3.8` libraries. Anyone that has the same issues I would recommend to do the same as a docker image is independent from your systems requirements and previous installations.